# A nontrvial inequality $\sum\limits_{\rm cyc}a^2 c(4a-3b-c)^2\ge 20abc\sum\limits_{\rm cyc}a(a-b)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, symmetric-polynomials, discriminant, uvw

> For real numbers $a,b,c>0$, show that 
>   $$\sum_{\rm cyc}a^2 c(4a-3b-c)^2\ge 20abc(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$$

This has the following dumbass notation:
$$\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
&&&&&\cdot&&&&&\\
&&&&\cdot&&16&&&&\\
&&&1&&-44&&-8&&&\\
&&-8&&35&&35&&1&&\\
&16&&-44&&35&&-44&&\cdot&\\
\cdot&&\cdot&&1&&-8&&16&&\cdot
\end{array}\ge 0$$

Exact equality takes place at cyclic permutations of $(1:1:1)$, $(4:1:0)$, and $(X:Y:1)$ where $X,Y$ are the largest real roots of $32X^3-132X^2+123X-32$ and $32Y^2-123Y^2+132Y-32$, and the domain cannot be extended to arbitrary real numbers.

So I saw this from social media and I cannot find a proof for this, as SOS did not take me very far. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I can find a Stefan type identity by computer. Does it help you?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "I saw this from social media and I cannot find a proof for this, as SOS did not take me very far" (I don't understand why "social media" are involved, and what is the meaning of SOS in this context 'Save Our Souls ?"

Comment: @JeanMarie, SOS means Sum of Squares (he tried to prove to inequality by writing the difference of the left side - right side as a sum of squares).

Comment: @JeanMarie see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chipped_beef

Comment: @Will Jagy I appreciate the humor. I will never more send a SOS without thinking to this possible interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(16a^4c+a^3b^2-8a^3c^2-44a^3bc+35a^2b^2c)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(32a^4c+2a^3b^2-16a^3c^2-88a^3bc+70a^2b^2c)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(16a^4b+16a^4c-7a^3b^2-7a^3c^2-88a^3bc+70a^2b^2c)\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}(16a^4b-16a^4c-9a^3b^2+9a^3c^2)$$ or

$$\sum_{cyc}(16a^4b+16a^4c-7a^3b^2-7a^3c^2-88a^3bc+70a^2b^2c)\geq$$
$$\geq(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)\sum_{cyc}(16a^2+7ab).$$
We'll prove that:

$$\sum_{cyc}(16a^4b+16a^4c-7a^3b^2-7a^3c^2-88a^3bc+70a^2b^2c)\geq0.$$
Indeed, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$,$abc=w^3$ and $u^2=tv^2$.

Thus, $t\geq1$ and we need to prove that
$$1296u^3v^2-1485uv^4-810u^2w^3+999v^2w^3\geq0,$$ which is a linear inequality of $w^3$,

which says that it's enough to prove the last inequality for an extreme value of $w^3$,

which happens in the following cases.

1. $w^3\rightarrow0^+$.

Let $c\rightarrow0^+$ and $b=1$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$16a^4+16a-7a^3-7a^2\geq0$$ or
$$16a^2-23a+16\geq0,$$ which is obvious;

2. Two variables are equal.

Let $b=c=1$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$32a^4+32a+32-14a^3-14a^2-14-88a^3-176a+140a^2+70a\geq0$$ or
$$(a-1)^2(16a^2-19a+9)\geq0,$$ which is true because $$19^2-4\cdot16\cdot9<0.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$1296u^3v^2-1485uv^4-810u^2w^3+999v^2w^3\geq(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)(144u^2-75v^2)$$ or
$$9(48u^3v^2-55uv^4-30u^2w^3+37v^2w^3)\geq(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)(48u^2-25v^2),$$
for which it's enough to prove that
$$81(48u^3v^2-55uv^4-30u^2w^3+37v^2w^3)^2\geq(a-b)^2(a-c)^2(b-c)^2(48u^2-25v^2)^2$$ or
$$3(48u^3v^2-55uv^4-30u^2w^3+37v^2w^3)^2\geq(3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6)(48u^2-25v^2)^2$$ or
$$(1251u^4-2265u^2v^2+1183v^4)w^6+$$
$$+2u(1152u^6-4008u^4v^2+4682u^2v^4-1995v^6)w^3+v^6(12u^2-25v^2)^2\geq0.$$
Now, since $$1251u^4-2265u^2v^2+1183v^4>0$$ and $$(12u^2-25v^2)^2\geq0,$$ it's enough to prove our inequality for
$$1152t^3-4008t^2+4682t-1995<0,$$ which gives
$$1\leq t\leq1.6574...$$ and it remains to prove that:
$$t(1152t^3-4008t^2+4682t-1995)^2-(1251t^2-2265t+1183)(12t-25)^2\leq0$$ or
$$(7-4t)(t-1)^2(12t-13)^2(48t-25)^2\geq0,$$ which is true for
$$1\leq t\leq1.6574...$$

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not as apt as Michael Rozenberg's as it is found by computer software (not mine).

The following identity holds:

$$[4(a^2+b^2+c^2)+17(ab+bc+ca)](LHS-RHS) =$$
$$ 14abc\sum_{cyc}(4a^2-4b^2-3ab+8bc-5ca)^2+$$
$$\sum_{cyc}a(2 a^2 b + 12 a^2 c - 6 a b^2 - 10 a b c - 3 a c^2 - 8 b^3 + 25 b^2 c - 12 b c^2)^2$$

Comment: Very cool! May I ask which software is used?

Comment: Nice Sum of Squares.

Comment: @EdwardH., it's SageMath.

Comment: @Atticus   Can SageMath find SOS expression of (for example) $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+abcd+1 - (ab+bc+cd+da + ac+bd)$ (which is non-negative for $a, b, c, d\ge 0$)?

Comment: @RiverLi, a friend of mine has written a script for three variables homogenous polynomials in Sage (I don't have the knowledge or understanding to change it).

Comment: @Atticus  Thanks. Hope it is powerful. For non-contest inequalities, the Buffalo Way and SOS are two good methods. There are many inequalities in MSE and AoPS you may try. If you can find SOS for most of them, it is wonderful.

Comment: Can I have this code?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(a, b, c) = \mathrm{LHS} - \mathrm{RHS}$.
Suppose the inequality is true. Then $f(x_1^2, x_2^2, x_3^2)\ge 0$ for all real numbers $x_1, x_2, x_3$.
We wish $f(x_1^2, x_2^2, x_3^2) = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i^2$ where $f_i$'s are all polynomials.
This may be impossible. However, from Artin's theorem, there exists nonzero $g\in \mathbb{R}[x_1, x_2, x_3]$
such that $g^2f = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i^2$. A possible choice is $g = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2$.
It works. $(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2)^2f(x_1^2, x_2^2, x_3^2)$ is SOS (Sum of Squares).

We obtain the following SOS expression.
\begin{align}
&64(a+b+c)^2(\mathrm{LHS} - \mathrm{RHS})\\
 = \ &\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} 15 a (8 a^2 c+2 a b^2-13 a b c-2 a c^2-8 b^3+17 b^2 c-4 b c^2)^2\\
 &\quad + \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} a (8 a^2 b+24 a^2 c-30 a b^2-a b c-6 a c^2-8 b^3+49 b^2 c-36 b c^2)^2\\
 &\quad +174 a b c (4 a^2-3 a b-5 a c-4 b^2+8 b c)^2\\
 &\quad +58 a b c (4 a^2-13 a b+11 a c+4 b^2+2 b c-8 c^2)^2.
\end{align}

Reference:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_polynomial

Comment: Thanks! Yes I am aware of the Positivstellensatz, but in most cases I find it difficult/unrealistic to use. Wish I had known better.

Comment: @EdwardH.    Usually it is difficult to find a rational SOS if number of variables $n$ and degree $d$ are not small.

Comment: Could you explain how do you get this SOS, please?

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-972-algebraic-techniques-and-semidefinite-optimization-spring-2006/lecture-notes/lecture_22.pdf

Comment: Is there a program in Maple to help us get this nice SOS?

Comment: I don't know. I use Maple to factor, collect, simplify the expressions, implement the Buffalo Way. In the following post, NguyenHuyen use fsos function. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3693814/proving-inequality-by-sos

Comment: Sorry, if you can share to me your Maple please?

Comment: @knvy144444  I only use Maple to factor, collect, simplify the polynomial expressions.

Comment: I mean share me the Maple. Not the program to get SOS. Thanks.

Comment: @knvy144444  Maple is a commercial math software. You may try open-source software. see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open-source_software_for_mathematics